# Why is enqueueAcquireGLObjects() leaking memory in this OpenCL code?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, opencl

When I run the following OpenCL code in a loop with 400K elements, memory starts leaking.

```
std::vector<cl::Memory> cl_vbos;
glFinish();
cl_vbos.push_back(cl::BufferGL(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, VBOs.back(), &err));
queue.enqueueAcquireGLObjects(&cl_vbos, NULL, &event);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(globalWorkSize), cl::NDRange(localWorkSize), NULL, &event);
queue.enqueueReleaseGLObjects(&cl_vbos, NULL, &event);
glFinish();
queue.finish();
```

Even if I don't launch the kernel it leaks memory. Only when I comment:

```
queue.enqueueAcquireGLObjects(&cl_vbos, NULL, &event);
```

The program stops leaking memory. The weird thing is that memory is not leaking on the GPU but the CPU. Am I doing something wrong? Forgetting to release something?

I'm using NVIDIAs OpenCL 1.1 with the latest drivers on Windows 7 64-bit, and VC++.

Comment: Are you sure it is a real leak? Or one of those library leaks that does not really leak up to Infinity amount of RAM?. It looks like bad programming on the nVIDIA driver side.

Comment: Can you try &cl_vbos[0] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this after countless hours trying to debug the problem. It seems to me that the problem is NVIDIA related. I will leave my fix here just in case anyone has this same problem.

Anytime you pass an event to either of this functions:

```
queue.enqueueAcquireGLObjects()
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel()
...
```

A new pointer is created and is never freed. The fix is not using &event:

```
queue.enqueueAcquireGLObjects(&cl_vbos, NULL, NULL);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(globalWorkSize), cl::NDRange(localWorkSize), NULL, NULL);
queue.enqueueReleaseGLObjects(&cl_vbos, NULL, NULL);
```

I believe that using:

```
event.wait();
```

After enqueuing an event also fixes the leak, but have not tested this solution in depth yet.

Comment: Anytime you get an event back from an OpenCL API you are responsible for releasing it when you are done with clReleaseEvent. Otherwise you'll leak memory.

Comment: I'm using the C++ bindings, that in theory should do the clReleaseEvent on the destructor, right?

Comment: I'd trace it through and check.